# What happens when the Resource Manager (RM) goes down in Yarn?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2, high-availability

What happens when the Resource Manager (RM) goes down in Yarn?

In the middle of running a job, if the Resource Manager goes down, then what will happen to the job?

Does the job gets submitted automatically or do we need to submit the job again?

Thanks,

Venkat

Answer (score 5):

---

**Resource manager** (RM) high availability is explained in [Apache](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/ResourceManagerHA.html) link as follows.

[image]

**ResourceManager** HA is realized through an Active/Standby architecture.

At any point of time, one of the RMs is Active, and other standby node is waiting to take over if Active RM fails.

The RM being promoted to an active state loads the RM internal state from **State-store** and continues to operate from where the previous active left off.

A new attempt is spawned for each managed application previously submitted to the RM. Applications can checkpoint periodically to avoid losing any work.

The **State-store** must be visible from the both of Active/Standby RMs. Currently, there are two RMStateStore implementations for persistence - **FileSystemRMStateStore** and **ZKRMStateStore**.

The ZKRMStateStore (**ZooKeeper**) implicitly allows write access to a single RM at any point in time, and hence is the recommended store to use in an HA cluster.

Using the **ZKRMStateStore**, there is no need for a separate fencing mechanism to address a potential split-brain situation where multiple RMs can potentially assume the Active role.This situation is handled with ZooKeeper very well.

**ZooKeeper** is not only used for Resource Manager fail over. Many of applications now a days using ZooKeeper. Example of other fail over use cases in Hadoop - Name Node fail over also happens through ZooKeeper.  Have a look at [Name node fail over process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33311585/how-hadoop-name-node-failover-controller-process-works/33313804#33313804) too.

***After Hadoop 2.x and Before Hadoop 2.6.x***:

When a ResourceManager dies and is restarted, or fails over to another ResourceManager in the case of an HA cluster, the newly active ResourceManager instructs running ApplicationMasters to abort. This uses up an application attempt.

Also, if the ResourceManager is down for some time and the ApplicationMaster is unable to connect, it will timeout and abort. That uses up an application attempt too.

When a new ResourceManager becomes active, it can recover applications with failed attempts that have not exceeded their max-attempts.

Have a look at this [article](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/05/how-apache-hadoop-yarn-ha-works/) for more details

***From [Hadoop 2.6.0](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/ResourceManagerRestart.html):***

Resource Manager recovers its running state by taking advantage of the container statuses sent from all Node Managers. Node Manager will not kill the containers when it re-syncs with the restarted Resource Manager.

It continues managing the containers and send the container statuses across to Resource Manager when it re-registers.

Resource Manager reconstructs the container instances and the associated applications’ scheduling status by absorbing these containers’ information

Answer (score 0):

The admin will create a new resource manager.Will take the latest information from all the application managers and update the **Persistent Storage** which the new Resource Manager will use. It is purely an admin task

Answer (score 0):

- No application or task can be launched of RM is unavailable.
- If you have HA of RM then it will restart from HA.